# Issues with UIScrollView and touchesBegan

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

When a user touches one of the white UIViews, it runs its touchesBegan:

```
...

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        delegate.startedTouchingPage(page: self)
        ...
```

The delegate is the VC. startedTouchingPage is implemented in the VC as

```
    func startedTouchingPage(page: Page) {
        if (page.tool == .PEN || page.tool == .ERASER) {
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
            scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
```

I *thought* this would prevent scrolling and panning, and allow the pen to draw in peace. But instead, when I try to draw on the page, [the pen sometimes draws properly, and sometimes instead scrolls the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zNzK.gif).

It turns out that the times that the page scrolls instead of draws, touchesBegan didn't run, and thus startedTouchingPage didnt run either. I can't figure out why...